# C++ map insertion

Tags: c++, memory, dictionary

```
// Create sound effect
SoundEffect* newSoundEffect = new SoundEffect(frequencyArray);

if (soundEffects.find(name) == soundEffects.end())
    soundEffects[name] = (*newSoundEffect);

// Clean up memory
delete [] frequencyArray;
delete newSoundEffect;
```

`frequencyArray` (above) and `m_data` (below) are dynamically allocated.  `soundEffects` is a `std::map`.  Whenever I try to insert the value pointed to by `newSoundEffect` into `soundEffects`, the destructor of `SoundEffect` is triggered, and for some reason, when the destructor tries to delete `m_data`, I get the error "Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.  I read somewhere that this location denotes uninitialized memory or something.  But in the code snippet above, using Visual Studio's debugger, I can confirm that `m_data` in `newSoundEffect` pointing to a valid memory sequence.  What am I doing wrong?

```
~SoundEffect()
{
    if (m_data != NULL)
        delete [] m_data; // Error :(
}
```

**EDIT**: Owing to @Chad's suggestion, I went ahead and added a copy constructor to the `SoundEffect` class, but it hasn't helped, because although `newSoundEffect` is definitely constructed when I try to put it into `soundEffects`, the copy constructor receives an object with uninitialized member variables; an uninitialized `SoundEffect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SoundEffect` class will need a copy constructor and copy assignment operator to be used in this manner.

Read this:  [The rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)

Comment: Good idea.  I thought of that too, so I created a copy constructor, but when the copy constructor is accessed, both the calling instance and the instance passed in have uninitialized `m_data`...

Comment: What else might be causing this?

Comment: False alarm - something uninitialized *was* being passed into my copy constructor, but once I made sure nothing happens if an uninitialized value is passed in, I discovered that the proper value is passed in immediately after the invalid one.  Weird, but now it seems to be working.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Need to see the constructor.

But 0xCCCCCCCC in microsoft world means it has not been allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Implement a copy constructor to copy the bytes of m_data appropriately (by reallocating a new buffer, and appropriately copying the bytes).

Another answer:  Make your map a map of SoundEffect* (pointers) instead of SoundEffect instances. Don't delete newSoundEffect after inserting it into the map.

Answer (score 0):

`soundEffects[name] = (*newSoundEffect);` is trying to put a *copy* of the `SoundEffect` object into the map.

I'm pretty sure you just want to store a `SoundEffect*` as the map value, instead of a `SoundEffect` object.